# js function working on chrome, but not safari or firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, safari

This is my first time ever posting a question here, I apologize in advance if my post is not in the right format.

I'm working with a .js file that already works fine on Chrome, Firefox and Safari, I had to add a function that displays the errors (missing data) that my PHP script finds on an uploaded file (dragged and dropped) on a JQuery dialog box. My addition works fine on Chrome, but when I tried it in Safari and Firefox, I get js file errors, I am assuming my function is the problem, because it ran fine before my function.

This whole JS thing is new to me, and this is something I am implementing to already existing code. Can anyone tell me what in my dataCheck function is incompatible with Safari or Firefox? Am I using a method that causes my JS or JQuery to fail in those browsers?

1. user drops csv file.
2. js file gets called, file is uploaded via js upload function

   ```
   function upload(pfile) {
       $('#stage').css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
       $('#filelog').html("");
       $.loader({ className:"blue-with-image-2", content:'' });
       $.post("b13micro_upload.php", {queryString: ""+pfile+""}, function(data){
           $('#myfile').stop(true,true).fadeIn();
           $('#myfile').css('opacity',1);
           $('#myfile').css({'background-image':'url(/images/icons/blcir4.png)'});
           $('#myfile').html("<b>File Uploading Complete</b>");
           $("#fileupload-progress").hide();
           $.loader('close');
           dataCheck(data.uniqueid, data.base);
       },'json');
   } // upload
   ```
3. dataCheck function gets called, IF missing data then dialog pops informing the user. ELSE the next js function gets called.

   ```
   function dataCheck(uniqueid,base){
   $.post("dataCheck.php", {uniqueid : ""+uniqueid+""}, function(data){
       if (data.result != 'Failed'){
           check(uniqueid, base);
       }else {
           $.mobile.changePage( "#mydialog", { transition: "pop", role: "dialog"} );
           var dataArray = [];
           dataArray = data.result_array;
           var missingdata = "";
           var i;
           var length = dataArray.length;
           for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
               missingdata += "Row: " + dataArray[i] + "<br>";
           }
           $('#checkresults').append(missingdata);
           $('#myheader').html(data.message);  
           $('#fail').live('click', function(e){
               $('#myheader').html("");
               $('#correct').html("");
       });
       }
   },'json');
   location.reload();}
   ```

Comment: FYI pretty good first question, that's refreshing. Anyway, can you open up the dev console on the browers that aren't working to see if there are any errors?

Comment: I suggest adding "alert" statements to display information while your JavaScript and jQuery executes. This can provide useful feedback to determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: @JohnH I'm a bigger fan of console.log(); Get's less annoying if you have loops or repeated alerts.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions! What apparently was happening was that location.reload() was being called as soon as my code ran, on both Safari and Firefox, and my dialog box was not appearing. I deleted that function and it works just fine now. I am not sure why it worked in Chrome, maybe it was ignoring the function?

Comment: **debugging tip:** try removing each line, one by one, until it works in all browsers. this narrows it down to the line that’s causing the problem. then once you figure out what’s causing the problem, you can ask a more targeted question.